Sub-Gaussian $X_t$, prove $\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in T}X_t \right] \leq 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\rho(t,s)\leq \delta}(X_t-X_s) \right]+J(\delta,T)$
This is a question-and-answer just for me, but if you have alternate answers or comments, feel free to share them.
Let $(T,\rho)$ be a metric space and $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ be a sub-Gaussian process indexed on $T$, i.e., $X_t$ has means zero and  we have
$\displaystyle \begin{equation} \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda (X_s-X_t))] \leq \exp \left(\frac{\lambda^2 \rho(s,t)^2}{2}\right) \tag*{} \end{equation}$
for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s,t\in T$.
Definition note. Some authors omit the requirement that the mean should be zero. However, we follow the definition in Wainwright's "High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint" and impose that the mean is zero. The same can be said about the definition of a sub-Gaussian RV in the following answer.
Let $\delta>0$ and $D=\textrm{diam}(T) = \sup_{s,t\in T}\rho(s,t)$. Then my problem is as follows:

Prove the following: $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in T}X_t
 \right] \leq 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\rho(t,s)\leq \delta}(X_t-X_s)
 \right]+J(\delta,T) \tag*{}$

Here, $J(\delta, T)=2D \sqrt{\log{N(T,\rho,\delta)}}$ and $N(T,\rho,\delta)$ is the $\delta$-covering number of $(\rho,\delta)$.
Definition note:  $\delta$-covering is a subset $C$ of $(T,\rho)$ such that for any $t\in T$, there exists $c\in C$ such that $d(t,c)\leq \delta$. The cardinality of the smallest $\delta$-covering is the $\delta$-covering number, $N(T,\rho,\delta)$.

For this problem, bounding the expectation of the supremum is crucial. The following inequality can help in this case.
Proposition. Let $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ be $\sigma^2$-sub-Gaussian random variables. That is, each $Z_i$ has zero mean and satisfies the inequality
$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda Z_i)] \leq \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right)\tag*{}$
for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then, we have
$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{i}Z_i\right] \leq \sqrt{2\sigma^2 \log{N}}\tag*{}$
Proof. As the definition of sub-Gaussianity revolves around exponential functions, we multiply by and $\lambda$ take the exponent of the LHS. As the exponential function is convex, by Jensen's inequality,
$\exp\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\lambda\max_{i}Z_i\right] \right) \leq \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda\max_{i}Z_i)]\tag*{}$
We would like to take off $\max_{i}$ out of the exponent so that RHS is closer to the definition of sub-Gaussianity, but this is not possible if $\lambda<0$ since $e^{\lambda x}$ is decreasing in this case, meaning the maximum wouldn't be preserved. However, as the sub-Gaussianity is true for any $\lambda$, there is no harm in assuming $\lambda\geq 0$. Now, Since $e^{\lambda x}$ is increasing, or order-preserving, we have
$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda\max_{i}Z_i)] =\mathbb{E}[\max_{i}\exp(\lambda Z_i)] \tag*{}$
Finally, we want to put $\max_{i}$ out of the expectation, but we cannot do that in general. Thus, we want to replace $\max$ by an operation commutative with expectation. Since expectation is linear, sum or scalar multiplication fits the bill. Indeed, we have
$\mathbb{E}[\max_{i}\exp(\lambda Z_i)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\sum_{i}\exp(\lambda Z_i)] = \sum_{i}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda Z_i)]$
Finally, using the sub-Gaussianity assumption,
$\displaystyle \sum_{i}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda Z_i)] \leq \sum_{i}\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) = N\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right)\tag*{}$
Overall, we have
$\displaystyle \exp\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\lambda\max_{i}Z_i\right] \right)  \leq N\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) \tag*{}$
Reorganizing the inequality, assuming $\lambda>0$, we have
$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{i}Z_i\right]   \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\log{N} +\frac{\lambda\sigma^2}{2} \tag*{}$
If we set $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{2\log{N}}{\sigma^2}}$, we get the inequality. $\square$
Let us now solve our problem.
Solution. Our problem seems to be an infinite-dimensional analogy to the proposition proven above. Moreover, we need to take an $\delta$-covering as the definition of $J$ involves it. So, for $\delta>0$, take the smallest $\delta$-cover $\mathcal{C}=\{t_1,\cdots t_N\}$ where $N=N(T,\delta, \rho)$.
Reviewing the proposition above, $J(\delta, T)$ will most likely be used to bound a supremum looking similar to $\max_{s\in \mathcal{C}}X_{s}$. Thus, we will see something like $(X_t-X_s)+X_s$ to create the RHS, and $t,s$ should satisfy $\rho(t,s)\leq \delta$. We can use $\delta$-covering to satisfy this. For any $t\in T$, define $s(t)$ to be $s(t)\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $d(t,s(t))\leq \delta$. If there are multiple $s(t)$, we choose one of them.
Now, we can write
$\begin{align} \sup_{t\in T}X_t &= \sup_{t\in T}(X_t - X_{s(t)} + X_{s(t)})\\ &\leq\sup_{t\in T}(X_t - X_{s(t)} + \sup_{t\in T}X_{s(t)}) \\&= \sup_{t\in T}(X_t - X_{s(t)}) +\sup_{t\in T}X_{s(t)} \\ &\leq \sup_{\rho(s,t)\leq \delta }(X_t - X_{s}) +\max_{s\in \mathcal{C} }X_{s}  
 \\ &\leq 2\sup_{\rho(s,t)\leq \delta }(X_t - X_{s}) +\max_{s\in \mathcal{C} }X_{s}\tag*{}\end{align}$
For this, it is enough to prove that $X_{s},s\in \mathcal{C}$ is $D^2$-sub-Gaussian, and we can bound the second term using the proposition.
For clarity, we denote the expectation in terms of a random variable $X$ by $\mathbb{E}_{X}$. We want to prove that $\mathbb{E}_{X_s}[\exp(\lambda X_{s})]\leq \exp\left(\lambda^2 D^2 /2\right)$. We note that $E_{X_t}[X_t]=0$ by definition. Therefore, for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}_{X_s}[\exp(\lambda X_{s})] & = \mathbb{E}_{X_s}[\exp(\lambda X_{s} - \lambda E_{X_t}[X_t])] \\ &= \mathbb{E}_{X_s}[\exp(E_{X_t}[\lambda (X_{s}- X_t)])] \\ &\leq \mathbb{E}_{X_s}\mathbb{E}_{X_t}[\exp(\lambda (X_{s}- X_t))] \cdots \textrm{Jensen for }\mathbb{E}_{X_t} \\ &= \mathbb{E}_{X_s,X_t}[\exp(\lambda (X_{s}- X_t))]\cdots \textrm{Fubini's theorem for expectation} \\ &\leq \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \rho(s,t)^2}{2}\right)\cdots \textrm{sub-Gaussianity of }X_t \\ &\leq \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 D^2}{2}\right)\cdots \textrm{Definition of supremum}\end{align}$
Therefore, $X_s$ is indeed $D^2$-sub-Gaussian, and thus by the proposition, we have what we want.
